# What's a simple way to send statistics from my game back to me?

Tags: unity, c#, statistics

For example, I set up my game to keep track of how many times people play x, y, and z game modes, and also to keep track of how often players reach a certain point. What's a simple way to send this data to me so that I can see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Unity, I would just recommend using their analytic service, which allows you to store String data (not just numeric data like many services) so you can capture things like which game mode or level was most played, user hardware specs, basically anything.

https://unity3d.com/services/analytics

The API is also very simple to use and integrate, much simpler then most other services I've tried.

Comment: Make sure you [read the legal requirements](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityAnalyticsDataPrivacy.html) you need to fulfill in order to use Unity Analytics. If your game sends data to Unity before you gave the user the opportunity to opt out, you are breaking the EU GDPR. (this also applies to any other method of statistics collection, by the way)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to setup a web server that saves the data.

Make the client send data once in a while via http.

Save the data in a database like MySQL, and create a page to view the data.
Remember to add security if you're sending anything critical.

And since the legal aspect of apps is getting more and more complex, make sure you have your users agree to that fact in the ToS, and make sure you review your app with a competent lawyer.